# Is there any way to get just the mini boxplot from a seaborn violinplot?

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I'm trying to draw a very long series of boxplots. I like the aesthetic of the miniature boxplots drawn inside [violinplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html) (controlled via the "inner" parameter to seaborn.violinplot). Does anyone know of an easy way to draw just this mini boxplot without the rest of the violinplot? Thanks!

[image: seaborn violin plots]

Comment: I'm trying to do the opposite, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create a subclass of violinplot that does what I want. Basically I just copied the code that draws the voilins and deleted the parts I didn't need. This is obviously a little ugly but it did the job. If anyone else comes up with a more elegant solution please post your answer.

You can find my solution at:
https://gist.github.com/mdbecker/c21e6a8a6ce893b61eecd880d9f18a83

Which produces results like:

[image: miniboxplot]

Comment: Great work. Just out of curiosity, who are your audience, researchers, developers or other group of individuals? And since this plot removes the violin part that better presents distribution, do you think it will be well accepted?

Comment: The audience will be researchers/clinicians/myself. The data I'm visualizing is all normally distributed so showing the distribution is redundant. I'm visualizing the AUC of a model over time to get a sense if the model is drifting over time (I suspect that it is). I'm using bootstrapping to generate samples for the boxplots. Depending on the results I may be the only person to look at these charts :-D.

Answer (score 2):

The violins are `PolyCollection` objects. You could remove all `PolyCollection`s from the axes. This would make sense if the axes only contain the violin plots and not any other `PolyCollection`s in addition.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(style="whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.violinplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips)


from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection
for a in ax.findobj(PolyCollection):
    a.remove()

ax.relim()
ax.autoscale_view()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Or even simpler,

```
for a in ax.collections:
    a.remove()
```

Comment: Clever solution! I wasn't aware of the findobj function. Very handy!

Comment: You don't need `findobj`. I added a solution without it.

Comment: One downside of this approach is the ylim is based on the version of the plot that includes the violinplots which means you'd have to explicitly set the ylim afterwards. In my case this is okay because I'm already setting the ylim anyway but this might be an issue others run into if they use this approach.