# Seaborn: Violinplot experiences difficulty with too many variables?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I wanted to use seaborn to visualize my entire Pandas dataframe with violinplots, and I thought I had made the necessary corrections to generate a large graph for the sizable number of 270 variables my dataframe possessed.

However, no matter what I do, the violinplots only display their inner mini-boxplots (as another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52971882/is-there-any-way-to-get-just-the-mini-boxplot-from-a-seaborn-violinplot) describes) for each variable, and not their kde's:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(50,5))
ax.set_ylim(-6, 6)

a = sns.violinplot(x='variable', y='value', data=pd.melt(train_norm), ax=ax)
a.set_xticklabels(a.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90);

plt.savefig('massive_violinplot.png', figsize=(50,5), dpi=220)
```

[image]

(apologies for the cropped graph, the whole thing is too big to post)

Whereas the following code, using the same `pd.Dataframe`, but only showing the first six variables, displays correctly:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
ax.set_ylim(-6, 6)

a = sns.violinplot(x='variable', y='value', data=pd.melt(train_norm.iloc[:,:6]), ax=ax)
a.set_xticklabels(a.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90);

plt.savefig('massive_violinplot.png', figsize=(10,5), dpi=220)
```

[image]

How could I get a graph like the above for all the variables, filled with proper violinplots showing their kde's?

Comment: If you try to put too many plots on one figure, a) you get the problem you've described, and b) it ceases to be useful as a visualization for the data. One option is to group features you want to compare directly, and present each group on a different subplot. Another is to only show a few features that tell something useful about the data and discard the rest. Barring that, the only other option is to have an obscenely huge plot area, but that's not a great idea for so many reasons.

Comment: I understand the value of separating a task into separate chunks, but in the niche data processing context I have, it is better to view all the variables at once, and there must be a way to do it.

For ex., as seen here in my browser, https://imgur.com/71VD65x 
it is completely feasible to deal with such large graphs, and there definitely seems to be enough room for seaborn to generate the true violinplots.

However, when I keep extending the `figsize` of the graph, eventually it starts breaking down, as seen here, https://imgur.com/hQWOjKn

Comment: You could always break it down into chunks to where the images look good, then use an imaging tool to manually group the images together. As long as you keep the y axis the same value, you should be able to do it pretty easily, and it would not take more than 5 min.

Comment: As you've seen, a  `(3000, 5)` plot is not really feasible within a normal seaborn use case. Bottom line is that 270 plots is just not going to display very well side by side. You might stack multiple subplots vertically (45 should be enough at 6 per subplot) and show a subset on each, but really the best option is probably to look into other visualization libraries. Bokeh, for interactivity, perhaps?

Comment: I am [unable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3CV2.jpg) to reproduce the problem with random data. Try to work out a [mcve].

Comment: Goyo, thanks for the interest in my question! Since there is no way to easily share a csv file on stack, I decided to upload it here, http://www.yourfilelink.com/get.php?fid=2025783

Comment: Please _always_ share your CSV files in Stack Overflow itself. The supplied link is now a redirect to a spam site, and so is of no use to a reader wanting to learn from the question. In general, if a required file is too big to post in a question, the question is off-topic. Usually all examples can be cut down though.

Answer (score 6):

This is not related to the number of variables or the plot size but to the huge differences in the distributions of the variables. I can't access your data right now so I will ilustrate it with a made up dataset. You can follow along with your dataset, selecting the three variables with more dispersion and the three with less dispersion. As a dispersion measurement you can use the variance or even the data range (if you don't have crazy long tails) or something different, I am not sure what would work better.

```
rs = np.random.RandomState(42)
data = rs.randn(100, 6)
data[:, :3] *= 20
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

See what happens if we plot the density with common axes so they are directly comparable.

```
df.plot(kind='kde', subplots=True, layout=(3, 2), sharex=True, sharey=True)
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: Density with common axes]

This is more or less the same you can see in the seaborn violin plot but of course transposed.

```
sns.violinplot(x='variable', y='value', data=pd.melt(df))
```

[image: Default seaborn violin plot]

This is usually great for comparing the variables because you can look at the differences in width as differences in density. Unfortunately the violin for the variables with more dispersion are so narrow that you can't see the width at all and you lose any sense of the shape. On the other hand the variables with less dispersion appear too short (actually in your dataset some of them are just horizontal lines).

For the first problem you can make the violins use all the available horizontal space by using `scale='width'` but then you no longer can compare the density across variables. The width is the same at the peaks but the density is not.

```
sns.violinplot(x='variable', y='value', data=pd.melt(df), scale='width')
```

[image: Seaborn violin plot with scale='width']

By the way, this is what matplotlib's violin plot does by default.

```
plt.violinplot(df.T)
```

[image: Matplotlib default violin plot.]

For the second problem I think your only option is to normalize or standardize the variables in some way.

```
sns.violinplot(x='variable', y='value', data=pd.melt((df - df.mean()) / df.std()))
```

[image: Standardized violin plot]

Now you have a clearer view of each variable separately (how many modes they have, how skewed they are, how long the tails are...) but you can compare neither the scale nor the dispersion across variables.

The moral of the story is that you can't see everything at once, you have to pick and choose depending on what you are looking for in the data.

Comment: Insightful help, thanks a lot, Goyo. In that case, I started experimenting with the `width` parameter, setting it very high as in the following code, `sns.violinplot(x='variable', y='value', data=pd.melt(train_norm), linewidth=0.8, width=40, ax=ax)`, and I got the following results, which *seem* like what I was looking for: https://imgur.com/WiRtxyv .

By having set the `width` so high, am I disturbing the true dimensions of the kde's somehow, like you did with `scale='width'` above?

Comment: That's a weird question. There are no "true dimensions" since you don't have a true scale in the X axis. All the violins have the same area so that they can be compared. I would argue that the plot with all variables is an ugly mess with all those overlapping violins (you are showing only the nice part in your link) but if you find it useful just use it.

Comment: That is true that I am only using the nice part of it as the example image ^^. I was wondering about whether they all had the same area, if they would be comparable, so thanks for answering that.
I will keep your advice in mind and try to find a way to standardize the variables more than they already are (the data is for the kaggle Housing competition), and keep my mind open to other possibilities.